# ForeignKey setup clarification on updating related fields

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key

Considering these two tables in PosgtreSQL:

```
# report
+----+-------------+--------------------+
| id | report_name | report_description |
+----+-------------+--------------------+
| 1  | RPT         | ABCDEFGH           |
| 2  | TST         | LMNOPQRS           |
+----+-------------+--------------------+

# report_years
+----+--------------+-------------+------+
| id | report_id_fk | report_name | year |
+----+--------------+-------------+------+
| 11 | 1            | RPT         | 2019 |
| 12 | 1            | RPT         | 2020 |
| 13 | 2            | TST         | 2019 |
+----+--------------+-------------+------+
```

1. Given that `report_id_fk` is a foreign key in the `report_years` table, there wouldn't be a way to `CASCADE` and update the `report_name` based on `report_id_fk`?
2. They would have to be separate foreign keys?
3. `report_name` shouldn't even be in the `report_years` table in the first place since it is redundant and should just be queried over with a `JOIN` to `report`?
4. Is it possible to have a multifield foreign key constraint such that `report_name` and `year` would be required for a `CASCADE`?

For example:

```
# report
+----+-------------+------+
| id | report_name | year |
+----+-------------+------+
| 1  | RPT         | 2018 |
| 2  | RPT         | 2019 |
| 3  | RPT         | 2020 |
+----+-------------+------+

# report_details
+----+-----------+----------------+---------+---------+
| id | report_id | report_name_fk | year_fk | details |
+----+-----------+----------------+---------+---------+
| 11 | 1         | RPT            | 2018    | ABC     |
| 12 | 2         | RPT            | 2019    | DEF     |
| 13 | 3         | RPT            | 2020    | GHI     |
+----+-----------+----------------+---------+---------+
```

5. If I wanted to change the `report_name` for `year = 2020` in `report`, it would `CASCADE` to `report_details` and update the `report_name_fk` based on the `report_name_fk` and `year_fk`?
6. Or (back to question 1), can I setup a `CASCADE` that would updated `report_name_fk` and `year_fk` in `report_details`?

I can see how to do this with a manual `UPDATE`, but seeing if it is possible with `CASCADE`. Or, like I think, this is redundant, should be avoided and if you need to know `report_name` and `year` for a report in `report_details`, you should just write a query an `JOIN` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve this with a two-column foreign key and cascading update, but that requires a redundant two-column unique constraint on `report`, which will harm DML performance and use extra storage space.

The proper solution is to remove the redundant column from `report_years`. This concept of removing redundancy from a data model to improve consistency is so important that there is a name for it: normalization.